# Does array_walk_recursive use tail call optimization?

Tags: php, tail-recursion

Just a simple curiosity. I couldn't find anything on Google, and I definitely don't want to dig into PHP source.

Does [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) implement tail call optimization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, no :)

See also: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/array.c#L1097

Comment: Is there any way to use TCO then?

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Some languages have optimizations for this, but unfortunately PHP does not; so if you're thinking of using this feature it's probably better to make it iterative instead (which is the poor man's TCO)